# os x swift build package manager cannot find shared library from unixODBC C dependency

Tags: c, swift

On OS X El Capitan, I am attempting to integrate a **swift** wrapper for **unixODBC 2.3.4**, but the build fails at the linker step with the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lodbc.2 for architecture x86_64`

I immediately confirmed that the installed library is in fact 64 bit:

```
file /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

For my project, I am utilizing the **swift package manager**, so I have installed the latest developer bits for swift and prepended its bin folder to my `PATH` environment variable:

`export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH`

I installed **unixODBC 2.3.4** successfully using homebrew and created the requisite odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini files to access a postegresql database.  I confirmed that the odbc installation and configuration are correct by connecting to a remote database with the isql utility included by unixODBC.

In my **CunixODBC** swift project I created the following **module.modulemap** file referencing the newly installed unixODBC shared library

```
module CunixODBC [system] {
   header "/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include/unixodbc_conf.h"
   header "/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include/sql.h"
   header "/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include/sqltypes.h"
   link "odbc" 
   export *
}
```

In my **swiftodbc** project that establishes the dependency on CunixODBC, my Package.swift file is:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "../CunixODBC", versions: Version(0,0,4)..<Version(1,0,0))
    ]
)
```

As additional confirmation that unixODBC is functioning correctly, I wrote a small test program in **C** and linked to the unixODBC shared library.  My compile string is:

```
cc  -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include -lodbc odbctest.c -o odbctest
```

The compile and link succeed and resulting executable works as expected.

What step or configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding: `-Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib` to your `swift build` instantiation.

Comment: I gave it a try and unfortunately it did not work.  The first attempt generated the following error: `swift build -Xlinker /usr/local/lib
Linking swiftodbc
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/lib' for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-03-01-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/cwhelan/development/swift/swiftodbc/.build/debug.yaml default'

Comment: The message indicated that it wanted a full file path so I next tried the full path to the odbc library: swift build -Xlinker /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib.  This eliminated the "can't map file" error, but the error from the original post returned.

Comment: Sorry it should have been: `-Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib`